# How to allow -- in category name

Tags: urls, filters

How allowed "--", "---" or any other symbol in terms(category) **URL**.
Now WordPress replace from "--" to "-"

ps.I`m using to Subdomain plugin. And IDN subdomain Example: xn--...site.com/ There xn-- is category (url)

Answer (score 1):

The -- to an mdash conversion happens inside wptexturize() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize which is applied to many things (including taxonomy titles and other functions output.

Look for places you might want to remove the filter from in wp-includes/default-filters.php and remove the filter with the remove_filter() function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter

Comment: I have changed Taxonimy before asked. This is wrong way.
formatting.php
Work comments line 930 //$title = apply_filters('sanitize_title', $title, $raw_title, $context);
This is bad but worked decision